# Google Map fails to load after changing element ID with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm trying to load a google map into a div. Because I have an indeterminate number of these DIVs, each of which has to have an independent map loaded into it, I wanted to do a jQuery search for the DIV class, then change the IDs of the found elements to make them unique. This works fine. However, when I try and load a map into each DIV, it fails to load. Here's my code as it stands:

```
function gmapEditor(mapobj) {

    var mapdivid = jQuery(mapobj).attr("id");
    var mapopts = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.520707, -0.006866),
        zoom: 9,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        labels: true
    };

    initmap();

    console.log(mapdivid); // -> 'ell-gmap-kml-mapdiv-11740'
    console.log(mapobj);

    function initmap() {
        //jQuery(mapdivid)[0]
        gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapdivid), mapopts);
        //gmap = new google.maps.Map(mapobj[0], mapopts);
        mapcenter = gmap.getCenter();
    }
}
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    // Create array to hold map editor instances
    var maps = new Array();

    jQuery(".ell-gmap-kml-mapdiv").each(function (i) {
        // Add prefix to map div ID
        var newid = jQuery(this).attr("id") + '-' + jQuery(this).data("post_id");
        jQuery(this).attr("id", newid);

        // Instantiate new map editor object and add to array
        maps[i] = new gmapEditor(jQuery(this));
    });
});
```

(dunno why the code formatting has screwed up there).
As you can see, I'm creating an independent instance of my 'gmapEditor' object for each DIV with class 'ell-gmap-kml-mapdiv' that is found by jQuery.

If I comment-out the code that changes the ID of the map DIV, the map loads. The problem is, since there's no longer a unique ID for each DIV, all the maps will have identical settings.

I've added a couple of console-dumps. With the ID-changing code re-enabled, I get the expected value for 'mapdivid'.
Interestingly, I also see from the log that a load of sub-element have been added to the mapobj DIV, so something is working, somewhere. The Maps API isn't completely failing to get a handle to the map DIV, but it's also not able to display anything there. I can even see these extra elements if I do 'inspect element' in Safari, but on the actual page, the map is not visible.

Anyone any clues as to what might be going wrong, and how I might fix it, if that's possible? Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way entirely...

Incidentally, I've tried this in Safari, FireFox and Chrome on the Mac, with the same result each time.

Any advice much appreciated.

EDIT:

Now working. I have no idea why it wasn't working before, but here's the working code:

```
function gmapEditor(mapobj) {

var mapdivid = jQuery(mapobj).attr("id");   
var mapopts = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.520707, -0.006866),
        zoom: 9,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        labels: true
};

initmap();

console.log(mapdivid);
console.log(mapobj);

function initmap() {
    gmap = new google.maps.Map(mapobj[0], mapopts); 
    mapcenter = gmap.getCenter();
}   
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

// Create array to hold map editor instances
var maps = new Array();

jQuery(".ell-gmap-kml-mapdiv").each(function(i) {
    // Add suffix to map div ID
    //var postid = jQuery(this).data("post_id");
    //var newid = jQuery(this).attr("id") + '-' + jQuery(this).data("post_id");
    var newid = jQuery(this).attr("id") + '-' + i;
    jQuery(this).attr("id", newid);

    // Instantiate new map editor object and add to array
    maps[i] = new gmapEditor(jQuery(this));
});
});
```

I decided to simply add an index onto the ID, rather than using a data attribute of the element as I had before, but I was able to get it to work that way, too.

Comment: No sweat - hey, you got it figured out. And maybe everything you have written down up there will end up helping someone else. That's what it's about anyway.

Comment: Yep, hopefully it will be of use to someone.